# Mapping a read-only database with a many-to-many relation without a join table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a question similar to [@ManyToMany without join table (legacy database)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5409560/387981) with an additional issue.

I have two tables `A` and `B`

- `A` with a multiple column primary key (`ID` and `ID2`)
- `B` with a multiple column primary key (`ID` and `ID3`)

An row in `A` can reference several rows in `B` (`B.ID = A.ID`) and a row in `B` can be referenced by several rows in `A`.

**EDIT**: the database is a read-only legacy database that I cannot change. I do not need to map the relationships with JPA (I could just do it in my program logic with additional selects) but it would be nice.

It is basically a many-to-many relationship without a join table. Since, as for the linked question, I just have to read the tables, I tried with two one-to-many relationships in both classes.

The additional problem that I have is that both `ID`s used for the join are not the primary key.

I have the following classes:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "A" )
@IdClass( PrimaryKeysA.class )
public class A {

    @Id
    @Column( name = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "char" )
    private String id;

    @Id
    @Column( name = "ID2", insertable = false, updatable = false )
    private int id2;

    @OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    @JoinColumn( name = "ID", columnDefinition = "char", referencedColumnName = "ID" )
    private Set< B > setOfBs;

}

@Entity
@Table( name = "B" )
@IdClass( PrimaryKeysB.class )
public class B {

    @Id
    @Column( name = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "char" )
    private String id;

    @Id
    @Column( name = "ID3", insertable = false, updatable = false )
    private int id3;

    @OneToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
    @JoinColumn( name = "ID", columnDefinition = "char", referencedColumnName = "ID" )
    private Set< A > setOfAs;

}
```

Hibernate generates the following error:

```
Exception while preparing the app : referencedColumnNames(ID) of package.B referencing package.A not mapped to a single property
```

I don't really get the message: `B.id` is referencing a single property in `A` (`A.id`).

EDIT: as requested:

```
public class PrimaryKeysA implements Serializable {

private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;

private int    id1;
private int    id2;

    // getters/setters/equals/hashcode

}
```

`PrimaryKeysB` is similar with id3 instead of id2. Both classes `A` and `B` are simplified (anonymized) examples.

Comment: I don't really see how you can have a many-to-many with these tables. A.ID references B.ID, and B.ID is B's primary key. So a given A can only reference one B. You just have a ManyToOne association from A to B.

Comment: Ooops sorry I have the same on A as in B. I'll edit the question (I tried to generate a simplified example going too far)

Comment: This is not a many-to-many association between two tables...  Why are you using two ids on each table?  Do you have the ability to change this schema into a more standard form or is this a legacy database?  If it is not a legacy database, what is your reason for not using a join table if you want a many-to-many association?

Comment: @joncarl No it's a legacy read-only database. Otherwise I would have chose a better design. I could also avoid the mapping of the relationships and just define the entities. I wanted to try to map it to be able to avoid to many selects.

Comment: @joncarl, actually it is a many to many association. For each A there are several related Bs and for each B there are several As. The design is bad but semantically it is a many-to-many association.

Comment: Please post the code of `PrimaryKeyA` and `PrimaryKeyB`.

Comment: @tscho I posted a shortened version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a view that would act as join table:

```
CREATE VIEW AJOINB AS
SELECT A.ID as AID, A.ID2 as AID2, B.ID as BID, B.ID3 as BID3
FROM A JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

And then map it in JPA as a ManyToMany with AJOINB as join table.

If A.ID2 and B.ID3 were unique by themselves, you wouldn't even need to map A.ID and B.ID in your JPA beans.

Comment: Since the DB is read-only I would have to create a new DB with a copy of all the tables plus the additional view (since I don't think that I could define two entities on a DB and the join table on another). Having to use an additional DB I would then try to refactor the data in a better way. But could be worth ...

Comment: Depends on your DB. In Oracle and SQL Server you can use table aliases. And creating a view across schemes is possible even in MySQL.

Comment: Yes creating the view in another schema is no problem. I fear (I didn't check) that defining an entity in one schema with the join table in another will not work. But I will have to work with a DB link since the DB (not only the schema) is read only: I have no other access.

Answer (score 2):

Can you share some sample records from you tables?

The problem is very clear. For any one-many relationship, on the "one" side, there should be only one record that can be uniquely identified. Here, i think, since id is not unique there are multiple entries.

You may try to use @JoinColumns and add both the columns to uniquely identify the entity on the "one" side.

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="yourID1", referencedColumnName="yourID1"),
    @JoinColumn(name="yourid2", referencedColumnName="yourid2")
})
```

I'm assuming that you have the following data.

## table A:

```
id2    c1          id
100    content1    1000
101    content2    1001
```

## table B:

```
id3    s1          id
100    content1    1000
101    content2    1000
102    content3    1001
103    content4    1001
```

Here id2 and id3 are unique. A.id is unique but b.id is not; a typical OneToMany scenario.

If I map A to B using A.id and B.id, then this becomes one-to-many where A(100) can refer to B(100, 101) as the id is 1000

This will work fine i think. But if you have to map from B to A using the same columns (as stated in the question) it will not work as the one side (B) has duplicates.

Am I understanding your question correctly?

Comment: By the way I dont know how to add this as comment without posting something as answer. Can someone help me?

Comment: Hibernate complains on the many side. I have an A.id1 which is referencing B.id1. B.id1 is not unique (one-to-many). Hibernate complains telling me that B.id1 is part of a primary key: but who cares. For each A.id1 I have more B.id1s. If B.id1 is also **part** of the primary key of B should not be relevant. The tables are only related through id1 (id2 does not exist in B).

Comment: You need a reputation of 50 to be able to comment

Comment: @Matteo Can you remove the B to A association and try, so that the problem can be narrowed down?

Comment: Without association everything is OK. I could also live without the association and correlate when selecting.

Comment: Using your example: Assume A.id = 1000. This is in one-to-many relationship with B.id (content1 and content2). It works only if B.id is not part of the primary key of B. But as your example shows this should be no problem (B.id is not unique and should not be otherwise it would be a one-to-one relationship)