# Hibernate/JPA Join Two Tables With Composite Keys (No Foreign Relationship)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm fairly new to using JPA/Hibernate. I'm trying to figure out the best way to join two tables with composite keys and no real database relation.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovSXR.png)

```
@Embeddable
public class StepPK implements Serializable{
    @Column(name = "step_id")
    protected String stepId;

    @Column(name = "packet_id")
    protected String packetId;
    ...
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "step_def")
@IdClass(StepPK.class)
public class InprocessPacketStep implements Serializable{

    @Id
    private String stepId;

    @Id
    private String packetId;

}


@Embeddable
public class StepDetailPK implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "step_id")
    protected String stepId;

    @Column(name = "packet_id")
    protected String packetId;

    @Column(name="user_id")
    protected String userId;

    @Column(name="parallel_step_id")
    protected String parallelId;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "step_detail")
@IdClass(StepDetailPK.class)
public class InprocessPacketStepDetail implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String stepId;

    @Id
    private String packetId;

    @Id
    private String parallelId;

    @Id
    private String userId;
}
```

What I have so far works great when pulling information out of the tables individually, but I need some way to join them on the step_id. Since there's really no assigned relationship, doing a OneToMany and JoinColumns doesn't seem to work.

I've tried using a ManyToMany and it doesn't blow up when compiling, but upon inspection on my tests, it's causing a SQLGrammar Exception.

My only other thought is to manually join them through a query, but running `entityManager.createQuery("select InprocessPacketStep step join inprocessPacketStepDetail d on d.stepId = step.stepId")` causes a runtime error.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. I've spent quite a bit of googling trying different things I've found without success.

Comment: Oh, the image link at the top is basic table description

Comment: More information on the errors encountered please. Also, what output are you trying to get?

Comment: why can't you use additional relational table? What is the relation between these entities?

Answer (score 0):

If your database schema is not a legacy and you **can** change it, then `@ManyToMany` association with additional relationship table should do the trick:
[image]

There are plenty of [examples](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-many-to-many-annotation-mapping-tutorial/) in the web for popular JPA 2.x implementation frameworks (including Hibernate of course)

Otherwise you should try solution from this thread:
[@ManyToMany without join table (legacy database)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409560/manytomany-without-join-table-legacy-database)